# how to select all but certain rows in matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix

Is there an easy way to do this in r with a matrix, similar to negative indexing for data.frames?

for example, I can remove the n-th row of the matrix mat as follows:

```
mat = rbind(mat[1:(n-1),],mat[(n+1):nrow(mat)])
```

but are there faster and/or simpler ways to do this?

-Paul

Comment: Did you actually try negative indexing in matrices as you would do with `data.frame`? For example `df <- head(mtcars) ; df[-2,] ; as.matrix(df)[-2,]`. Did something didn't work? Can you show us an example matrix and desired output?

Comment: tried to delete this question but wasn't able to -- moderator?

Comment: This question does not deserve 5 down votes. It was clear exacly what I was asking I showed an effort, and was polite. The only thin wrong with it is that granted it was a very stupid question -- but that is not one of the criteria we use for downvotes is it? Just trying to keep above 100 till the big answer somes along

Answer (score 2):

Negative indexing works for matrices, i.e. `mat[-n,]`